# Spring Batch BeanWrapperFieldExtractor for large number of fields

Tags: spring, spring-batch, filewriter

I am in process of writing a Spring Batch application that reads a CSV file, does some transforming and writes a modified CSV to be sent to another batch process.

My writer configuration looks like this:

```
 <beans:property name="lineAggregator">
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator">
        <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                 <beans:property name="names" value="column1, column2, column3, column4 ------ 322 fields " /> 
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>

            <beans:property name="format" value="%-8s%-12s%-11s%-16s" ----322 fields /> 
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
```

I have to write around 322 fields. I am unable to get any `FormatterLineAggregator` to do my work. If I write the format like

```
<property name="format" value="%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%f;%f;%s;%f;%f;%td.%tm.%​tY;%td.%tm.%<‌​tY;%s;%td.%tm.%&‌​lt;tY;%s;%s;%s;%s;%t‌​d.%tm.%tY" /> ,
```

its getting really messy and its tough to make sure all fields are correct.

I thought of 3 different solutions:

1. Either go with the approach above.
2. Write a `CustomEditorFieldsExtractor` but don't know what to write in the class and how to format the fields (preferred).
3. Use a "non-standard" BeanIO framework jar but I fear my client won't agree to this solution.

Can someone please provide some inputs. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with solution #2 in this way:

1. Externalize how to format every property of you bean class (eg, in XML or text file)
2. Write a custom `LineAggregator` and make it works coupled with directive at point 1

---

```
class Aggregator implements LineAggregator<T> {
  private Map<String, String> propertyFormat;

  public String aggregate(T item) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(final String property : propertyFormat.keySet()) {
      final String format = propertyFormat.get(property);
      final Object propertyValue = /* Extract property from item using Spring beans */;
      sb.append(String.format(format, propertyValue));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```